how to redirect https to http in burpsuite
How to automatically modify https url to http url while intercepting using Burp Suite.
Below is the attempt made, but url is still being used as "https"
have tried replacing header as "^Host: foo.example.org$" to "Host: localhost:4000" where header is being updated, but need to update URL as well.
Thanks




The match/replace rule you're using only rewrites the Host header (ie the first line of the HTTP request) but does not impact which server the request gets sent to. To redirect the request to a different server, you can use the the Target Redirector extension as shown below:

If this is confusing, it's because generally the url informs both the Host header and the server to which the request is addressed:
              /--> DNS --> IP to send the request to
url -> host -<
              \--> Host header to include in the request

But those two things, the host header, and the destination hostname / ip, are in fact completely separate. You can connect to any IP that will listen, and send it any Host header you want.
